# Cucumber does not read data from scenario outline

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have following scenario outline

```
 Background:
   Given customer is in hot or not page

 Scenario Outline: Hot article
  And customer enters <name>
  And submits
  And customer clicks thumbs up
  Then ensure the TBD

 Examples:
  | name |
  |  Elliot |
  |  Florian |
```

and following step implementation -

```
@And("customer enters <name>")
public void customer_enters_name(String name) throws Throwable {
    // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

But when I execute test then I get following error -

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

```
@Given("^customer enters Elliot$")
public void customer_enters_Elliot() throws Throwable {
  // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
  throw new PendingException();
}

@Given("^customer enters Florian$")
 public void customer_enters_Florian() throws Throwable {
  // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
  throw new PendingException();
}
```

Did I implement test steps wrong?

Comment: Try "<name>" (in quotes) instead of <name>

Comment: this works, could you mark your comment as an answer and I would accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 Scenario Outline: ...
  And customer enters <name>
  ...
```

Do this (Note the double quotes)

```
 Scenario Outline: ...
  And customer enters "<name>"
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, The same error arise when in the runner class ,we put the wrong package of the step class

```
@CucumberOptions(glue = {"com.wrongpackage.step"})
public class TestRunner{

}
```

Step class should be present and the package should be correct.