# Gherkin not recognizing examples for scenario outline

Tags: parsing, cucumber, gherkin

I'm new to writing features in gherkin, and am getting an error on my very first scenario outline.

```
#language:en

Feature: Create an account
    In order to become a member
    As a new user
    I can create an account

Scenario Outline: View the account creation page
    Given I am at the "<page>" page
    And I have selected "<lang>" language
    When I see the Sign Up link in my language
    And I click the "<size>" Sign Up link in my chosen language
    Then I see the User Account page in my chosen language
    And the Create New Account tab in my chosen language

    Examples:
        |page           |lang       |size   |
        |landing        |English    |large  |
        |landing        |English    |small  |
        |FAQ            |English    |large  |
        |Forums         |English    |small  |
        |landing        |Francais   |large  |
        |landing        |Espanol    |small  |
```

When I run 
    cucumber --dry-run
I get the following error:

```
Missing Examples section for Scenario Outline at [filename].feature:8
(Cucumber::Core::Gherkin::ParseError)
```

Originally I had the variables in angle brackets without quotes, and added quotes following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358745/cucumber-does-not-read-data-from-scenario-outline) but alas, it didn't help with my situation.
Any ideas what my mistake is?
Thanks!

Comment: try outdenting your examples block

Comment: No dice :( Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: can you share some code that support your feature file?

Comment: I don't really have any- I'm writing these for manual testing right now, and eventually they will be tested in behat but that doesn't exist yet.  Happily (and frustratingly) I found the issue and it had nothing to do with the gherkin... but it's solved anyway :) Thanks to those who tried to help!

Comment: i copied you code and made a simple a simple test using eclipse and it works, could be some hidden strange characters in your original file.

Comment: ah yeh, maybe check to make sure you don't have mixed spaces and tabs.